# finding the value of $a$ for minimal solid

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Given that $y=x^2+ax-0.25$ is bounded by $x=0$ and $y=1$ and spinning around the x-axis.

What is the value of $a$ for min volume of that solid?

**My attempt**: $x^2+ax-0.25=1$ so $x=\frac{-a\pm \sqrt{a^2+5}}{2}$.

Then, $f(a)=\pi \int_{0}^{\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+5}}{2}}(1-(x^2+ax-0.25)^2)dx$

But that will lead to: $f(a)=1/480 (-225a+20a^3+8a^5+200 \sqrt{5+a^2}-8a^4 \sqrt{5+a^2})π$

And then $f'(a)=0$ will be very hard to solve.

Any ideas?

**Update**: wolfram gave me an answer but i wonder if it can be done without that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think you overcomplicated the problem.

You only need to find out what is the minimum of :

$f(a)=\int_{0}^{\frac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+5}}{2}}|x^2+ax-0.25|dx$

Since the volume is going to be the rotation of this area around the axis $x$. If you minimize the area, you minimize the volume.

The function $y=x^2+ax-0.25$ has a positive zero in $x=\dfrac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+1}}{2}$, which is smaller than $\dfrac{-a+\sqrt{a^2+5}}{2}$, so that divide the integral in two domains.

Comment: so i can use that reasoning: "if the area is minimize so is the volume"? and i didn't understand about why i need to divide the integral.

Comment: I'd appreciate if you can elaborate in the answer.

Comment: @aron I am wrong in fact. I thought that using the fact that it was with a max $y$ of 1 was allowing this, but there is no reason why $|y|$ would be limited in fact...

Comment: so what can we do?